# MongoDB scripting

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Essentially, I am trying to create a large number of users to test my app with.

I have tried a variety of different versions of this script but none are working.

> Adding one user works as expected:
>   `db.users.insertOne({<test-user-json>})`

## BUT

> when I try adding bulk users like this, it doesn't work:

```
db = connect('localhost:27017/_testDB');

const numArr = new Array(100);

const usersToAdd = numArr.map((e, i) => ({
    name: 'foo bar',
    email: `foo${i}@bar.com`,
    avatar: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/849/200?blur=3',
    password: 'asdfasdf',
    date: Date.now(),
  }))

db.users.insertMany(usersToAdd);
```

I've also tried looping through a forEach and using insertOne to individually add them, since it does work on it's own, but this doesn't work either.

Is there a reason? What is the difference between MongoDB JavaScript and regular JavaScript? e.i. `console.log` is `printjson()` What else is different? Should I be using the mongDB NodeJs driver? The mongoDB documentation page on scripting seems pretty sparse..

And or, what is the best way to create a large number of arbitrary users and other administrative tasks?

I was about to write a bash script to get this working, but I figured I'd ask here first.

Answer (score 0):

## Got it!

```
var bulk = db.users.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  bulk.insert({
    name: 'foo bar',
    email: `foo${i}@bar.com`,
    avatar: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/849/200?blur=3',
    password: 'asdfasdf',
    date: Date.now(),
  });
}
bulk.execute();
```